# Multiple conditions in While controller not work

Tags: jmeter

I need multiple conditions in While controller, but if I have more then one condition every time is infinite loop.

```
${__javaScript("${type}" != "book",)} && ${__javaScript("${author_surname}" != "Novak",)} && ${__javaScript("${author_name}" != "John",)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article I think you need to put all the conditions into single [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) like:

```
${__javaScript("${type}" != "book" && "${author_surname}" != "Novak" && "${author_name}" != "John",)}
```

also as per the function documentation:

> javaScript is not the best scripting language for performances in JMeter. If your plan requires a high number of threads it is advised to use __jexl3 or __groovy functions.

so it worth considering migrating